# How do I show the entire calculation in the output?

Tags: java, primes, decomposition

Good evening,

I'm a beginner in java and I was assigned to code a program to decompose prime number.
This is what I've got so far.

```
package introductionProgramming;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Primes {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                int primo;

    primo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inform prime number: "));

        while (prime % 2 == 0) {
            prime = prime / 2;
        }
        while (prime % 3 == 0) {
            prime = prime / 3;
        }
        while (prime % 5 == 0) {
            prime = prime / 5;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, prime);
                }
    }
```

So the decomposition part seems to work but I need the output, if entered the number 180, to look similar to this:

```
180  2
90   2
45   3
15   3
5    5
1
```

I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps OP means calculation?

Comment: How about, in each of your `while` loops, before you do the division, you could print out the dividend and the divisor.  Would that work for you?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was in a rush. I fixed it already.

Comment: @DavidWallace Could you show how to do it? I'm new and really confused but I think it might work. :)

Comment: @user3674747 you need out put to your dialog ?

Comment: @KickButtowski Not really. It doesn't matter how I show the decomposition as long as I show it.

Comment: Are you actually asking me to write code to show you how to print values to your console?

Comment: @DavidWallace well, I think so. As I said, I'm a beginner and I don't know a lot of simple things. I tried using system.out.print but I don't use it correctly. So far I've only used JOptionPane.

Comment: OK, if you don't know how to use `System.out.print` or anything similar, I suggest you start with an easier project than this one.  Perhaps working your way through the online Java tutorials would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

To send the calcultation as a whole to the output, you will need to gather all results and send it as a whole. To achieve this, when finding each result, you will add the appropriate text to a StringBuffer object, that will gather the results where ultimately it will be displayed. Below is an example of your code.

```
public class Primes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    int prime = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inform prime number: "));
    StringBuffer resultsBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    while (prime % 2 == 0) {
        resultsBuffer.append(prime+" "+2+"\n");
        prime = prime / 2;

    }
    while (prime % 3 == 0) {
        resultsBuffer.append(prime+" "+3+"\n");
        prime = prime / 3;

    }
    while (prime % 5 == 0) {
        resultsBuffer.append(prime+" "+5+"\n");
        prime = prime / 5;

    }

    resultsBuffer.append(prime+" "+1+"\n");



    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resultsBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you even run this code to see the outcome of your code?

Comment: Yes, it shows all the results, but now noticed the OP also wants the divisor next to the result, editing the answer.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't do what the OP wanted.  It also seems a bit pointless putting everything in a list to print afterwards, instead of just printing each time you divide.  Lastly, if you insist on storing things in a list and iterating at the end, I would recommend using an enhanced for loop.

Comment: for love of God, can you come with good message that makes sense on the screen? so you can get voted up

Comment: Yes, agree with you David. Updated the example.

Comment: I don't think `resultsBuffer.append(prime+" "+1+"\n");` is in the right place.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Needed to be out of the while loop, thank you.